# Selenium css selectors on element with huge list of classes

Tags: selenium, automation, css-selectors

I've been working on automation of a product that uses Dojo. The html I'm working with is very messy.. I need to click on div that has following css selector

> div.dijit.dijitReset.dijitInline.dijitLeft.dijitTextBox.dijitComboBox.dijitDateTextBox.dijitValidationTextBox.dijitTextBoxError.dijitComboBoxError.dijitDateTextBoxError.dijitValidationTextBoxError.dijitError

I'm using firefinder plugin in Firefox and it can see the element all the time, out of 2 chrome plugins I have (CSS selector tester and CSS and Xpath checker) only the first one can find the element.

When I run my selenium code I get `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException`.

I tried selecting classes with `.` and with `[class=".."]` as well and both failed.

Is there some selenium limitation on how many classes you can have assigned to your element before it stops seeing an element? What stable approach can I use to make my tests work?

Comment: Without seeing the HTML, my best guess is the element you're trying to interact with is inside of a frame or iframe.

Comment: As @Richard mentioned, seeing the code will help us to help you.

Comment: Ok, i think i figured it out.. So the browser plugins i used would add some other classes to highlight the element and once i select it once it would add another class on top of that list of classes and somehow i missed it.. 

So to answer my own question.. there are no limitatins on class list per element, also the browser tools can help to find element but could also cause some weird issues..
 
Thank you for your help right away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FirePath plugin in firefox and look for unique classes so you only have 1 unique selector. Also look up CSS selectors, they will help you in the long run

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp